# Change the tab selection color in TabBar SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, tabbar

I am trying to change the color of selected tab in TabBar, but nothing worked. I can change the TabBar `backgroundColor` by writing

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
    }
    var body: some View { 
    }
}
```

In swift, we set `tintColor` and it does change the color of selected tab. But what do i need to do for swiftUI?

Here is my code,

```
    TabView(selection: $selection) {
        AView()
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "bubble.left.and.bubble.right")
                    Text("A Tab")
                }
        }.tag(0)

        BView()
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                    Text("B Tab")
                }
        }.tag(1)

        CView()
            .tabItem {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.grid.3x3")
                    Text("C Tab")
                }
        }.tag(2)
    }
```

Any help with this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `accentColor`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview/3368073-accentcolor

```
TabView {
  // fill this out with your tabbed content
}
.accentColor(.orange)
```

[image]

Comment: This also affects elements within the `View` such as `Button`s though.

Comment: This sis bad way. This works with only systemIcons. If u provide custom icon this wont work their.

Comment: You're probably not setting up your `renderingMode` properly or your icon doesn't use transparency like it should.

Comment: While this gets the job done, it will have very random effects on the rest of the code. It affects `.navigationItem(leading: traling:)` for example, so you need to explicitly add `.tint` to those items to counteract it. Not sure what else is impacted.

Comment: The effects are not random in any way. Please look at the linked documentation to understand what it's doing. Probably more important to ask yourself why you want completely separate tab color vs app accent color.

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 15, another option is to use Assets

[image]

and you can use it in your code like

```
TabView {
    // custom tab item
}
.tint(Color(.tabAccent))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems [accentColor(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview/accentcolor(_:)) will be deprecated, if the deployment target is **iOS 15 or above**, we could use [tint(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/tint(_:)) instead like below,

```
TabView {
    // custom tab item
}
.tint(.purple)
```

Comment: this does not have any effect. Did anyone try that?